# Input field value with visibility hidden not getting posted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a select box with options of numbers in it.Whenever user selects an option i am displaying input box through jquery depending on the number selected.So for this the input box are initially hidden. Now the problem is that when i try to post the value of those input box, they are not getting posted.
Here is html code-

```
<form action="data.php" method="POST">
    Select the number of company:
      <select name="num_of_comp" id="num_of_comp">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>     
<div id="div1" style="visibility:hidden;">
<label for="dbname">database name:</label>
<input type="text" name="db1" id="db1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</div>
<div id="div2"  style="visibility:hidden;">
<label for="dbname">database name:</label>
<input type="text" name="db1" placeholder="db1 name"/>
<input type="text" name="db2" placeholder="db2 name"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</div>
```

Here is the script that dynamically displays the input box -

```
$('#num_of_comp').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="1"){
    $("#div1").css("visibility", "visible");
     $("#div2,").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
    else if( $(this).val()==="2"){
    $("#div2").css("visibility", "visible");
     $("#div1").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
```

Here is php code-

```
$i = $_POST['num_of_comp'];
if($i == '1'){
$db1 = $_POST['db1'];
echo $db1;
```

Here I am not getting the value of db1.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not set same id to multiple fields, id should be unique for all fields.

so set different ids to all fields in form

Even the name of the all input fields should be unique here.

Answer (score 2):

You have two inputs with name `db1`. The second value (input without `id`) overwrites the first one (input with `id="db1"`).

Answer (score 0):

This is your issue

You have use same id for two input fields that is wrong every id in the page should be unique otherwise you can't get the actual value of your expecting field, and use proper naming for those id then you wan't miss those issue and code will be clear also use different name for name attribute

```
<input type="text" name="db1" id="database1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />

<div id="div2"  style="visibility:hidden;">
<label for="dbname">database name:</label> 
<input type="text" name="db2" id="database2" placeholder="db1 name"/>
</div>
```